# How can i remove JUST the title tag from wp_head() function?

Tags: title, wp-head, wp-title

i'm using wordpress 4.6
i'd like to remove just the title tag automatically outputted by wordpress because need to hardcode the html title tag in the template.

i guess is something like this:

```
add_action('wp_head', '//remove title tag command');
```

but i didn't find any valid solution so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see everything added to `wp_head` in the file [`/wp-includes/default-filters.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L237).

If your theme supports the title tag, you can remove it entirely with `remove_action`:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1 );
```

Though it may be simpler/better to use `remove_theme_support( 'title-tag' )` in a child theme, which is what `_wp_render_title_tag` checks before outputting the title tag.

Answer (score 3):

Wordpress 5.7.1 with Yoast SEO installed
Working code is:

```
add_filter('document_title_parts', '__return_empty_array', 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( is_page('138') )
{
      add_filter( 'the_title', '__return_false' );
}

add_filter('wp_head', function () {
    if (!current_theme_supports('title-tag')) {
        return;
    }

    if (did_action('wp_head') || doing_action('wp_head') && is_single()) {
        $categories = get_the_category();
        // Assuming the post has many categories will take the first
        $category = reset($categories);

        if ($category) {
            echo '<title>' . $category->name . ' - ' . get_the_title() . '</title>' . "\n";
        }
    }
    echo '<title>' . wp_get_document_title() . '</title>' . "\n";
});
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title' , 'render_title' );
function render_title($title){
    return 'New title ';
}
add_filter(  'document_title_parts' , 'render_title' );
function render_title($parts){
    $parts["title"] = "My Prefix ". $parts["title"];
    return $parts;
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?